# Distribution of the Brownian motion at a stopping time

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, martingales, stopping-times

Let $H_a$ be the first hitting time of $a$, $H_a = \inf\{t ≥ 0 : B_t = a\}$, where $B_t$ is a standard Brownian Motion
Use Optional Stopping to compute the distribution of $B_{H_a∧H_b}$
for $ a< 0 < b$

The Optional Stopping theorem says the following:

Let $(X_t)t≥0$ be a uniformly integrable martingale with continuous
sample paths. Let $S$ and $T$ be two stopping times with $S ≤ T$ . Then $X_S$ and $X_T$ are in $L^1$ and $X_S = E[X_T |F_S]$

If we stop the martingale then we get boundedness in $L^1$ and from there we can get uniform integrability, hence the theorem is applicable. It is trivial to see that $H_a∧H_b$ is a stopping time, too.

My problem is to find the distribution. Do we generally want to find $P(B_{H_a∧H_b}\geq x)=?$ or do we look at the mgf and try to guess the distribution (since there is a result about exponentiating a martingale)?

Thanks!

Comment: Which values can the random variable $B_{H_a \wedge H_b}$ possibly take? (Hint: There are not many...)

Comment: Either $a$ or $b$. Can we say due to symmetry (consider $-B_t$) that their probabilities are equal?

Comment: Well, for $a=-b$ it's certainly symmetric, but in general it's not. Use the martingale property to show that $$\mathbb{E}(B_{H_a \wedge H_b}) = \mathbb{E}(B_0)=0.$$ Deduce that $$a \mathbb{P}(B_{H_a \wedge H_b}=a) + b \mathbb{P}(B_{H_a \wedge H_b}=b) =0.$$ Use that $$ \mathbb{P}(B_{H_a \wedge H_b}=a)  +  \mathbb{P}(B_{H_a \wedge H_b}=b)=1$$ to determine $\mathbb{P}(B_{H_a \wedge H_b}=a)$ and $ \mathbb{P}(B_{H_a \wedge H_b}=b)$.

Comment: If you make that an answer, I'd be more than happy to accept it and upvote it

Comment: Just go ahead and write an answer yourself... solve the problem by following the steps from my comment.